# Thousands of IF statements in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, text

I'm a beginner with Python. Currently I'm making a car reading tool just to build some programming skill. All works well.

When I get a fault code from a control module from a car, I get a P-code. Like:

P2348 and P21E2 (random P codes)

I can retrieve these P codes, but I want to add a little more info to them. P codes can be linked to a fault description:

> P2348 - Misfire detected (random)

I want my program to give the extended information, and not just the P code. There are thousands of P codes and I have them all with discription. But a thousand If statements would be bad coding. I could look the P code up in a textfile and get the complete string from it, but that's not really an option (unless it's possible in the code itself or compiled with the executable).

What would be a neat way to do this? I have encountered this problem before when I took programming lessons. I used IF statements then (about 20) and I hated it.

Comment: Use a dictionary: p code as key, info as value. Can easily be loaded from a JSON file.

Comment: Make a JSON file that maps codes to messages.  Then just [`load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) that file into a dictionary when you start your program. Or use a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
code_descr = {
   'P2348': 'Misfire detected',
   'P8866': 'Engine is on fire',
   'P7777': 'Tires missing',
}
```

then you can lookup a key in the dict, no `if` needed:

```
print('{} - {}'.format(code, code_descr[code]))
```

You can write code to read a database in some format (csv, json, etc) and generate the dict, so you have the descriptions external to the program

Comment: Did a quick test and it seems to work like a charm :-) Thank you! Now I just need a quick way to load the textfile to the dictionary format but I bet I can work something out.